# How can I pass custom attributes through the lxml.sax interface?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml, sax

I am using `lxml.sax` to modify an XML document, and I would like to pass custom attributes to the `startElementNS` method. My initial code is this:

```
from lxml import sax

class MyContentHandler(sax.ElementTreeContentHandler):
    def startElementNS(self, ns_name, qname, attributes):
        if qname == 'text':
            # the troublesome line
            super().startElementNS((None, 'div'), 'div', {'class':'page'})
        super().startElementNS(ns_name, qname, attributes)
```

However, as the [documentation](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.sax.ElementTreeContentHandler-class.html#startElementNS) notes, the `attributes` parameter needs to be an `Attributes` object, not a regular dictionary. Debugging revealed that the exact type is `sax.xmlreader.AttributesNSImpl`, but this class is not officially documented and I can't seem to instantiate it directly.

Is there any (official or hacky) way to supply my own attributes to the `startElementNS` method?

Answer (score 0):

A few more days of trial and error have revealed that the `startElementNS` function *does* accept regular Python dictionaries, but the keys have to be `(uri, localname)` pairs.

```
super().startElementNS((None, 'div'), 'div', {(None, 'class'):'page'})
```